# can you join an object to an armature which is allready set up

Tags: rigging, bones

i have a humanoid. i want to create an animation where she plays with her phone. i basically want to join the phone to her hand.

i have tried 3 different methods:

1. i have tried literally selecting the different parts of the model (baked skin, bones , etc...)  and the phone and pressing ctrl+j (nothing happens)
2. i have tried parenting the phone into her hand (nothing happens)
3. i have created a new bone coming out of her hand called phone holding bone... but im not sure what to do with it.  (the armature allready has its skin)

how can i join this block to this hand so the move together when im animating and i dont have to deal with person and phone seperatley.

[image]

ps)
(i created the humanoid as a vrm initially with vroid)

UPDATE)  i managed to join it to the hand using bone constraint properties on the phone... however this only worked in blender when i finished my animation and exported it as an fbx to unity the phone floated still and was unaffected by the animation. Apparently this is because unity doesnt handle blender bone restraints. so i return to my original ideas. how can i join / parent the phone into the hand?